# next js with MUI, can we edit the layout?

Tags: next.js

[image]

can we add hello in layout ? it is giving error

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The div should be inside the body tag not outside.

```
return (
 <html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div>Hello</div>
    {children}
  </body>

 </html>
)
```